# Проверить наличие точки в переменной

Tags: php

У нас есть какая-то переменная, нужно прервать выполнение скрипта в случае, если в ней нет точки.
Вот наработки:

```
$per1 = $_POST['info'];

if (preg_match("/./", $per1)) {
    выполняем скрипт
    }
    else {
    стоп
    }
```

Но они не работают. В чем ошибка?

Comment: точка - управляющий символ в регулярках. И под него подойдет любой символ (перевод строки может подходить, если выставлены правильные флаги).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вместо

```
 '/./'
```

Надо

```
 '/\./'
```